# UI Performance with custom border

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I am creating a user control in C# and I am adding my own border and background. Currently the background is 16 small images that I change depending on the status of the object. Performance wise, would I be better off using GDI+ instead of the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it will make a difference.

If you just blit a bunch of images that's fine and very fast with GDI and GDI+